# Cant install npm packages with out sudo

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to install node-debugger and can't install with out sudo. Using sudo gets me some unexpected sideeffects, so want to install with out sudo. Following is the error trace

```
 $  npm install -g node-inspector
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-inspector"
npm ERR! cwd /home/santhosh/dev/scaleqa/mean_tut/mean_io_original/scaleqaApp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/santhosh/dev/scaleqa/mean_tut/mean_io_original/scaleqaApp/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: It's recommended that [`sudo` should be used with `-g`/`--global` installs](https://github.com/npm/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff). So, what unexpected side effects does using it cause? Though, if really needed, you can follow the early advice of [taking ownership of the install directory​](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo).

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to use `sudo`; this is because when you install globally, NPM creates links from your bin folder(s) to scripts that run node and the specified scripts from the packages (making `node-inspector somescript.js` really run `node /path/to/inspector/node_inspector.js somescript.js`.

Those bin folders are protected to those who are not super users, therefore `sudo` must be used to elevate your access level and allow npm to write to those directories.

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked for `sudo` because you are installing the `npm module` globally i.e you are using `-g` and they are stored in bin which can be accessed by `sudo user` !

if you do not use `-g` i.e you install it locally it wont ask for `sudo` permission!